# Howto find out if a website uses webassembly without manually checking?

Tags: webassembly

I'm a newbie in webassembly and currently working on a research project. When I visit a website I can manually check if a page uses web assembly using Developer Tools of the browser. I'm wondering if there is any way for me to automatically (e.g., using a script or a library/tool) find out if a website uses webassembly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an update, I tried using Puppeteer API to run Chrome headless. Using the API, I was able to see the worker threads, their URLs, etc. However, still could not figure out if a worker thread belongs to or a type of webassembly.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to check manually? I don't even know how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I was able to find out how to do this. A group of researchers published a research paper and developed a tool called wasm-collector (https://github.com/m4riuz/wasm-collector) which hooks to WebAssembly instantiation functions used in JavaScript.