# How can we understand if a worker thread runs webassembly using Puppeteer API?

Tags: puppeteer, webassembly

Using Puppeteer API it is possible to see get the list of worker threads, their URLs and locations. But is it possible to find out if a worker thread runs webassembly or JavaScript using Puppeteer?

Comment: duplicate? [Howto find out if a website uses webassembly without manually checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967002/howto-find-out-if-a-website-uses-webassembly-without-manually-checking)

Answer (score 1):

Never used Puppeteer, so I am not sure it's appropriate, but I would suspect that if there is a way to polyfill instantiateStreaming and similar JS methods that are needed to compile WebAssembly's modules, to do some logging and then call the proper implementation, you might be able to find whether something is instantiating a WebAssembly module.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to find a way to log JS methods that are used to compile/instantiate WebAssembly modules as you suggested.